# magento: is there a way to "run profile" with cron?

Tags: magento

I have an export profile on magento 1.6 and I can run it manually ("Run profile in popup"), but I need it to run automatically every day. Is there a way to set up a cron job to do that somehow?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I used the following taken from (note: broken link, code is copied below):

http://www.premasolutions.com/content/magento-dataflow-exportimport-form-command-line

```
<?php
//THIS SCRIPT JUST INITIALS THE PROFILE TO BE RUN VIA MAGENTO ADMIN "RUN PROFILE IN POPUP". Its the same thing as click just via this file that you can run via cron
$profileId = 8; // SYSTEM - IMPORT/EXPORT - ADVANCED PROFILES <-- you need to go into your magento admin and grab the exact profile ID
   
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
umask(0);
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
  
$profile = Mage::getModel('dataflow/profile');
$userModel = Mage::getModel('admin/user');
$userModel->setUserId(0);
Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->setUser($userModel);
$profile->load($profileId);
if (!$profile->getId()) {
    Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError('ERROR: Incorrect profile id');
}
  
Mage::register('current_convert_profile', $profile);
$profile->run();
$recordCount = 0;
$batchModel = Mage::getSingleton('dataflow/batch');
echo "EXPORT COMPLETE. BATCHID: " . $batchModel->getId();
```

It worked properly on 1.5.x (not tested yet on 1.6.x, sorry).

If it works, it's only matter of scheduling a cron job to call the script automatically.

Regards, Alessandro

Comment: Answer should be posted/quoted here, instead of just linked. Getting 404 :(

Comment: Try... http://phpmysqltalk.com/1718-magento-dataflow-exportimport-form-the-command-line.html

Comment: this link is broken :'(

Answer (score 3):

There are other things to consider, but in short, all you need is

```
Mage::getModel("dataflow/profile")
    ->load(5) // id of the desired profile
    ->run();
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a cron script from 1.4.x.x that will run a profile. [Export Profile Script](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewreply/277875/)

In 1.4.x.x and later, given proper resources, the final part where it opens the dataflow_batch_export table and truncates it may be commented out if your system is properly cleaning out the contents on completion of the export. There for a while, we were having problems with dataflow_batch_import and dataflow_batch_export table growth due to failure to clean up after either operation because a memory leak interrupted their proper operations.