# Magento: Possible to run export profile from shell ssh

Tags: php, magento, export

I'm trying to export 18,0000 products from Magento and it gets stuck at the

```
 Warning: Please do not close the window during importing/exporting data
```

stage.

I've found that it's possible to quickly reindex this many products by using `php indexer.php --reindex <code>`

Is it possible to use something similar to force export all products, or run a dataflow profile by its id?

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7969118/magento-is-there-a-way-to-run-profile-with-cron

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This will run the export profile by ID and then clean the dataflow_batch_? table afterwards. Be aware that it runs as the command line user and can create cache files as that user which can be inconvenient under certain web server configurations. It wouldn't hurt to clear the cache after run.

For a while, on 1.4.1.1, this was the only way to export large quantities of product until we found the memory leak and fixed it.

```
<?php

/***********************
 * Import/Export Script to run Import/Export profile 
 * from command line or cron. Cleans entries from dataflow_batch_(import|export) table
 ***********************/

$mageconf = './app/etc/local.xml';  // Mage local.xml config
$mageapp  = './app/Mage.php';       // Mage app location
$logfile  = 'export_data.log';      // Import/Export log file

/* uncomment following block when moved to server - to ensure this page is 
 * not accessed from anywhere else 
 */

//if ($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] !== '<your server ip address>') {
//   die("You are not a cron job!");
//}


/* System -> Import/Export -> Profiles get profile ID from 
 * Magento Import/Export Profiles
 */

$profileId = 9;

/* Post run housekeeping table bloat removal
 * imports use "dataflow_batch_import" table
 * exports use "dataflow_batch_export" table
 */

$table = 'dataflow_batch_export';

/* Scan Magento local.xml file for connection information */

if (file_exists($mageconf)) {

$xml = simplexml_load_file($mageconf, NULL, LIBXML_NOCDATA);

$db['host'] = $xml->global->resources->default_setup->connection->host;
$db['name'] = $xml->global->resources->default_setup->connection->dbname;
$db['user'] = $xml->global->resources->default_setup->connection->username;
$db['pass'] = $xml->global->resources->default_setup->connection->password;
$db['pref'] = $xml->global->resources->db->table_prefix;

} 

else {
    Mage::log('Export script failed to open Mage local.xml', null, $logfile);
    exit('Failed to open Mage local.xml');
}


/* Initialize profile to be run as Magento Admin and log start of export */

require_once $mageapp;
umask(0);
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);

$profile = Mage::getModel('dataflow/profile');
$userModel = Mage::getModel('admin/user');
$userModel->setUserId(0);
Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->setUser($userModel);
$profile->load($profileId);
if (!$profile->getId()) {
    Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError('ERROR: Incorrect profile id');
}

Mage::log('Export ' . $profileId . ' Started.', null, $logfile);

Mage::register('current_convert_profile', $profile);
$profile->run();
$recordCount = 0;
$batchModel = Mage::getSingleton('dataflow/batch');

Mage::log('Export '.$profileId.' Complete. BatchID: '.$batchModel->getId(), null, $logfile);

echo "Export Complete. BatchID: " . $batchModel->getId() . "\n";

/* Connect to Magento database */

sleep(30);

mysql_connect($db['host'], $db['user'], $db['pass']) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($db['name']) or die(mysql_error());

/* Truncate dataflow_batch_(import|export) table for housecleaning */

$querystring = "TRUNCATE ".$db['pref'].$table;

mysql_query($querystring) or die(mysql_error());

?>
```

Comment: Thanks, I found a similar way that just completed. Got all 18,000 odd products out. 
When you say clear the cache. Do you mean the Magento cache or otherwise. If it's not Magento could you elaborate?

Comment: The Magento cache can get files written to it with different ownership than the web server uses (nobody, www-data, et.al.) to access Magento's cache when you run scripts from the command line or via system cron jobs. The server fetches up against a rock when it either can't read or write to the cache file. I also include the dataflow_batch_export table cleanout because Magento's god-awful housekeeping has left behind table bloat as large as a gig on this table if you don't check and truncate it every so often (seen on 1.4.x.x and previous).

Comment: @FiascoLabs : Is it possible to run admin -> system -> Import/Export by command line, because website shows time error for more than 20k products.