# How to add import option to our custom module?

Tags: magento, csv, import

I have created new custom module with the admin form like to create new Products. I have created successfully.All are working fine.But now i want to add one more feature to this module. We can import a products by CSV files from **system/import/export**.

Like this how am i import my fields By CSV files.I have no idea about to do this task.

There(under import) we have an entity types **"Products and customers"**. If i add mine entity type to there is enough? or it have any other solution?

Answer (score 0):

This may not be a direct answer, but Magento comes with a CSV importing function under System -> Import/Export. It seems that you've already discovered this functionality. 
So, you could set up a custom import profile, let a customer upload a products.csv via your module and then call the import profile from this module.

Your products.csv has to provide Magento's attribute and values structure you'll see when you export products with the export functionality.

BUT: Magento's default importing functionalities are very limited. F.e. it is not capable of importing configurable products by default. We're using third party modules for these tasks.

Comment: Thank you for your response. But i dunno how to import option to my custom module.This task takes me so long time. still now, i cant get any solution yar! I have referred so much forums. But there, I got a solution for adding custom attribute to the product only. Already i have created an export option to my custom module. Now i know the format to import by csv. But I cant get the import Action! could you help me yar? Really thank you for your response

Comment: The import action can be called by the code from Steve Robbins answer in this thread: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7969118/magento-is-there-a-way-to-run-profile-with-cron

Comment: I think, this link for exporting profile. But I'm looking for add import option yar!

Comment: Nope. This calls ANY dataflow profile, no matter if it's an import or export profile. All you need to do, is to create an import profile under System->Import/Export->Dafaflow - Extended profile, remember the profile's ID and execute it with the code :)

Comment: But that reference link shows me like "SORRY. WE CAN'T SEEM TO FIND THE PAGE YOU'RE LOOKING FOR." Thank you @

Comment: Hmkay Oo
Here's the code:

Mage::getModel("dataflow/profile")->load(5)->run();

5 is the profile's ID.

Comment: In data flow profile option, we have only customer and product entity type.